# Apply for spouse visa; lost earlier refusal letters

Tags: visas, canada, visa-rejections

I am from Gujarat, India. Last week my wife got a student visa for New Zealand.

I want to go with my wife, but in earlier years I got 4 rejections from Canada, and then I lost my all refusal letters.

Can I apply for a spouse visa without these letters?
(I will declare all rejections, I do not want to hide anything).

Added to that: how can I get back my lost rejection letters?

Comment: Have you checked your account at [myCIC](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/account.html)? You might find your refusal letters there.

Comment: Furthermore, even if you don't remember your login credentials at myCIC, you can give sufficient information to link all old accounts to a ones.

Comment: all do but i didnt get any information from that

Answer (score 2):

The New Zealand [Partnership-Based Temporary Visa Application](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz-1198-partnership-based-temporary-visa-application_april-2016_fa_web.pdf) form and [guidance](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/documents/forms-and-guides/inz-1199-partnership-based-temp-visa-guide_april-2016_v1.pdf) asks about visa refusals, whether you have ever been refused a visa/permit to visit, work, study or reside in any country, and to explain further (country, type, date(s), reason(s)). It does not direct you to attach copies of the document(s).

If you're unable to recollect those details, you would have to make a lost document request to Immigration, Refugees and Citizenship Canada (IRCC) through the [Access to Information Act](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=463&top=1). To do so, however, you would need to engage a representative, as you are not in Canada.

> [**Who can make a request under the Access to Information Act?**](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=458&top=1)
>   Canadian citizens, permanent residents and any individual present in Canada can make a request under the Access to Information Act. If you are none of the above, you can ask a representative, who is a Canadian citizen or permanent resident, to make a request for you, if you give that person written consent.